# laravel 5 delete method. always MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route

```
Route::delete('/customer_page/summary/{id}', 'ReservationController@delete_cart');
```

My controller function

```
public function delete_cart($id)
    {


        cart::findOrFail($id)->delete();

        return redirect('/customer_page/summary');
    }
```

My form

```
 @foreach($cart as $key => $val)
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ $val->room_type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $val->number_of_rooms }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $val->price }}</td>
                            <td>
                              <form action="/customer_page/summary/{{ $val->id }}" method="post">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect red"><i class="material-icons">delete</i>delete</button>
                              </form>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

I don't know why I always keep getting that error

Comment: its either you remove the starting `/` from your 'action'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `method="POST"` on your form, then inside of the form, use Laravel's `method_field()` helper: `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}`. Do not attempt to set your method to `delete` directly.

The other answer using the form helper package form laravel-collective will work fine too, but that's not included by default in Laravel anymore, so I thought it prudent to outline how to achieve this using raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following(RESTFUL)

```
Route::resource('reservations', 'ReservationController');
```

OR(NON RESTFUL)

```
Route::delete('delete/{id}',array('uses' => 'ReservationController@destroy', 'as' => 'My.route'));
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $item = Reservation::findOrFail($id);
    $item->delete();

}
```

View

```
@foreach($reservations as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>

        <td>
            {{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => 'reservations.destroy', $item->id]) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('id', $item->id) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

OR (for non restful)

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['My.route', $value->id], 'method' => 'delete']) }}
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the below

```
{!! Form::model($user,
['method' => 'DELETE',
'route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id],
]) !!}
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

// then you form goes here

```
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change method on form, from POST to DELETE

You see on route you have defined as DELETE:

```
Route::delete('/customer_page/summary/{id}', 'ReservationController@delete_cart');
```

Comment: The method attribute of form elements appears to only seem to support `get` or `post` [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). Does it also support `delete`? Either way, I think this is on the right track.

Comment: It still says MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @HPierce No, HTML forms only support GET and POST.